# How can I make these circular edges smoother?

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders, smooth

I punched holes into a mesh and applied a solidifier modifier to it. The outside looks smooth but the inner circles look slightly faceted. What would be some strategies to make the inside circles smoother? Tried adding sub division + auto smooth but it makes the shading look pretty bad.[image]

Comment: hello, how does your topology look like? maybe check my tuto here (it's in french but I think it's pretty easy to understand): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2zZ0JV_qqA

Comment: Maybe try a _Bevel Modifier_ before the _Subdivision Surface_ . Set the bevel angle to 90deg or just short of it, use at least 2 or 3 segments, and reduce the bevel size to pretty small (so the edges still look "neat" and not rounded).

Answer (score 1):

A quick route to this kind of surface:

[image]

- *Add Mesh > Extra Objects* shipped add-on enabled
- 'Honeycomb' created and adjusted, rotated to stand in XZ, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Rotation applied.
- *Simple Deform > Bend*  about Z, eyeballed to connection (more than 360)
- *Weld* modifier

Those modifiers applied, then ...

[image]

- Top and bottom edges <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extruded and  <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (about 'Median' pivot) flattened
- *Subdivision Surface*
- *Solidify*, and *Bevel* (by angle, 2 segments, Shape: 1, or near 1)